# Cannot connect google account to Samsung Galaxy Ace Plus S7500

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung, google-account, samsung-galaxy-ace

I am helping my girlfriend to connect her `Samsung Galaxy Ace Plus S7500` with a new android account. We set the phone to factory settings and are now trying to connect *a*(!) google account to the android phone. Both google accounts, the **new** **AND** the **old** one cannot connect via the settings.

The funny thing:

Logging into gmail with the new google account via the pre-installed browser works nicely. However connecting via `settings>accounts and synchronization` does not work and the error message is: `Wrong username or password`, even though the user credentials are the same as logged in via the browser. Furthermore, we have checked the password multiple times via `copy and paste` of the password.

Here are the details:

**Android Version:** `2.3.6`

**Kernel Version:**

```
2.6.38.121500
dpi@DELL203 #1
Tue Nov 20 00:04:25 KST 2012
```

**Buildnumber:** `GINGERBREAD.BULK1`

My add account screen looks like that:

[image]

Btw we are connected to our home WIFI, while doing this!

I really appreciate your reply if you have any idea, what also can be tried!

**UPDATE**

As explained in this thread: [Cannot connect my Galaxy Ace to my Google account](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/41330/cannot-connect-my-galaxy-ace-to-my-google-account)

I changed the date to 21.November 2015 and get a new error:

```
'Can't establish a reliable data connection to the server.'
```

I also tried to log into my gmail app, but the login failed as I get the same error again:

```
'Can't establish a reliable data connection to the server.'
```

Comment: See if the answer here is of any use to you: [Unable to Setup Google Account on Android 2.3](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/124342)

Comment: Does the account have two-factor authentication enabled?

Comment: @eldarerathis yep the two accounts have two factor authetification. And the phone number goes to  the same phone.

Comment: I don't think Gingerbread supported 2FA properly. I think you need to use an [app-specific password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833) for it (I have no way to test this, though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem happens when 2-step verification enabled to google account.
to solve this first of all disable 2-step verification method if possible, then try to do so-

- on username write as

  username@gmail.com
- make sure your password is correct (maybe)

see https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: Rather than disabling the 2-step verification, an alternate one time password can be produced. Google allows creating app passwords.

Comment: actually it worked for my device.. may be the device or operating system doesn't  support OTP option.